# displaying highlighted list items in vuetify 2.x

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm writing my first app in vuetify 2.x. The app is displaying a list of items which are objects with a text (`item.t`) string field and a checked (`item.c`) boolean field.

I would like to display checked items in the current theme color and the unchecked items in the opposite theme color (highlighted). It thus depends on the value of the `item.c` field value.

I assume that changing the them of the list item will kind of reverse the colors of its content. Black <-> white.

How could I do that ?

This is my list component:

```html
<template>
  <v-list dense>
    <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <v-list-item :key="item.r">
        <v-list-item-content class="font-weight-medium">
          <v-layout>
            <v-row align="center">
              <v-col cols="2">
                <v-row no-gutters justify="end">
                  {{ item.n }}
                </v-row>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="10" class="px-0">
                <v-row no-gutters>{{ item.t }}</v-row>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-layout>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-divider
        v-if="index < items.length - 1"
        :key="`divider-${index}`"
      ></v-divider>
    </template>
  </v-list>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "itemList",
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.$store.getters.currentListItems;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I tried many things without success and couldn't find an example how to do that.

**Edit**: since the items contains just text and no icons, maybe it's enough the change the background and text color. The nice thing of theme is that it also reverse icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by different ways by v-menu by v-select or v-combo-box
and here you can use option multiple
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/#dense
but i think you need to use combo-box
and here you have slots
freedom of thought

Comment: It's a regular list and I don't want to change it into a v-menu or v-select. I misused the term selected. The right term is highlighted. I want to highlight some list items based on a boolean field of the item object.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. It's a bit hacky but it does the job.

The solution is to use a style computed with a method receiving the item object as argument. The hacky part is the way I change the style.

The highlighted text and background colors swap with the dark or light setting. Switching the them switches all the colors.

```html
<template>
  <v-list dense>
    <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <v-list-item :key="item.r" v-bind:style="highlighted(item)">
        <v-list-item-content class="font-weight-medium">
          <v-layout>
            <v-row align="center">
              <v-col cols="2">
                <v-row no-gutters justify="end">
                  {{ item.n }}
                </v-row>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="9" class="px-0">
                <v-row no-gutters>{{ item.t }}</v-row>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-layout>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-divider
        v-if="index < items.length - 1"
        :key="`divider-${index}`"
      ></v-divider>
    </template>
  </v-list>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "itemList",
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.$store.getters.currentListItems;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    highlighted(item) {
      let backColor = "white";
      let textColor = "#1E1E1E";
      if (
        (this.$vuetify.theme.dark && item.c) ||
        (!this.$vuetify.theme.dark && !item.c)
      ) {
        [textColor, backColor] = [backColor, textColor];
      }
      return {
        "background-color": backColor,
        color: textColor,
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```